# Convert a Boolean table to a Boolean expression

Tags: boolean-computation

How do I convert a Boolean table to a Boolean expression using `BooleanMinterms`.

For example:

```
table = {{0, 0, 0} -> 0, {0, 0, 1} -> 0, {0, 1, 0} -> 0, {0, 1, 1} -> 
   1, {1, 0, 0} -> 0, {1, 0, 1} -> 1, {1, 1, 0} -> 1, {1, 1, 1} -> 0}
```

Comment: You'll want to use `BooleanFunction[]` instead…

Comment: @J.M. no, i know that i can use BooleanFunction[], but i need to know how to use BooleanMinterms to convert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
table = {{0, 0, 0} -> 0, {0, 0, 1} -> 0, {0, 1, 0} -> 0, {0, 1, 1} -> 
   1, {1, 0, 0} -> 0, {1, 0, 1} -> 1, {1, 1, 0} -> 1, {1, 1, 1} -> 0}

tab = Pick[table, table[[All, 2]], 1]
(* {{0, 1, 1} -> 1, {1, 0, 1} -> 1, {1, 1, 0} -> 1} *)

bMin = BooleanMinterms[#, {a, b, c}] &@tab[[All, 1]]
(* (a && b && ! c) || (a && ! b && c) || (! a && b && c) *)
```

Check the result

```
 TableForm[Reverse@Boole@BooleanTable[{a, b, c, bMin}], TableHeadings -> {None, {a, b, c, "bMin"}}]
```

[image]

The Mathematica documentation is the best source to learn Mathematica!

Comment: but if we check result it's wrong: !a &&!b must give 1 but in the table it's 0

Comment: @Zineb.l  I have made an edit. You are very quick!

Comment: Zineb.l You're welcome.

Comment: we didn't pay attention to an easiest way:  **BooleanMinterms[{3, 5, 6}, {a, b, c}]** where 3,5 and 6 represent the indice of the minterms with an output =1

Comment: @ Zineb.l You are right, however, you have only 3 pins (inputs). An 8 bit input has 256 rows, then your method becomes more difficult to act, while my method automatically determines "1".

Comment: exactly, so the best is your method, good

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer above of @rewi there is a direct and simple method

```
BooleanMinterms[{3, 5, 6}, {a, b, c}]
```

where 3,5 and 6 represent the order of the minterms with an output =1, you can see the link below for more information on how to extract boolean expressions from truth table using **Minterms**.
http://www.cs.ucr.edu/~ehwang/courses/cs120a/minterms.pdf